# Create a byte array with dynamic size in F#

Tags: .net, arrays, f#

In C# and Java a byte array can be created like this

```
byte[] b = new byte[x];
```

where `x` denotes the size of the array. What I want to do is to do the same thing in F#. I have searched for how to do it and looked for it in the documentation. I think that I'm probably using the wrong search terms because I can't find out how.

What I've found so far is that `Array.create` can be used like this:

```
let b = Array.create x ( new Byte() )
```

Is there another way to do it which is more similiar to the way it can be done in C# and Java?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you would want to create an uninitialized array and fill it later:

```
let arr = Array.zeroCreate 10
for i in 0..9 do
   arr.[i] <- byte(i*i)
```

It's the way you normally do in C#/Java, which is unidiomatic in F#. Think about it; if you forget to initialize some elements, you have to deal with `null` nightmares.

In almost all cases, you can always replace the above procedure by high-order functions from [Array module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370273.aspx) or array comprehension:

```
let arr = Array.init 10 (fun i -> byte(i*i))
```

or

```
let arr = [| for i in 0..9 do -> byte(i*i)|]
```

Take a look at [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233214); it contains useful information about using Array in F#.

Comment: What "`null` nightmares"?
Both Java and C# do implicitly initialize elements of a byte array to bytes with value 0.

Comment: I meant the use of `Array.zeroCreate` with objects in general. There is no problem with this specific case.

Answer (score 20):

A closest F# analog would be [Array.zeroCreate:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340488)

```
let b: byte [] = Array.zeroCreate x
```

Instead of implicit array elements initialization to `0` bytes on Java and C# platforms F# makes the initial value of array elements obvious.

As to `dynamic size` of `b` in F# it is defined once by `x` value at the allocation and cannot be changed later by changing `x`, similarly to C#/Java,.

Answer (score 9):

```
let b = Array.create<byte> x 0uy  //Array.zeroCreate<byte> x
```

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean?

**F#** has a syntax different from **C#** and **Java**, you are using the `Array` module to let him create an array with an initializer. Nothing strange, one language is functional while the other is imperative so these differences are indeed needed.

According to the **F#** language specs you can't declare something that is uninitialized (unless using specific patterns as the `Option` type which are just exploits that allow you to express the uninitialized concept without really having it), that's why you have to pass an initializer for elements in the array.

Comment: "*According to the F# language specs you can't declare something that is uninitialized*" Eh, `Unchecked.defaultof<>` and `Array.zeroCreate` would like to have a word with you...

Comment: This is a caveat to let you exploit a language which is not meant to be used in such a way. `Unchecked.defaultof<T>` is a `null` value required for interoperability with .NET framework, you should never use it though, as it should be unnecessary in a functional language. The fact that is legal doesn't mean that is is suggested or designed by the language philosophy.

Comment: There's a difference between "can" and "can't".

Comment: Perhaps instead of saying what you cannot do, you should say what you can do instead.