# FSharp Make a partially-filled array of bytes

Tags: f#

I have the following C# code:

```
    this.UP = new byte[10];
    this.UP[1] = 2;
    this.UP[2] = 2;
```

I am attempting to port it to F#.  I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063962/create-a-byte-array-with-dynamic-size-in-f) post and can do it using Array.ZeroCreate and then mutating the 1st couple of bytes but I was hoping to do it in a more idiomatic way.  I have done this so far:

```
member this.UP = [|byte(2);byte(2);|]
```

Is there a way to initialize the rest of the array with empty bytes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is obviously too specific to your example but it should point you in the right direction:

```
let xs = Array.init 10 (fun i -> if i < 2 then 2 else 0)
```

For example, if you're copying from a smaller array, you could do this:

```
let ys = [|2uy; 2uy|]
let xs = Array.init 10 (fun i -> if i < ys.Length then ys.[i] else 0uy)
```

Another idea:

```
let xs = [| for i in 1 .. 10 -> if i <= 2 then 2uy else 0uy |]
```

Another idea:

```
let xs = Array.concat [[|2uy; 2uy|]; Array.zeroCreate 8]
```

It's worth noting, however, that all of these involve iterating over much of the array to replace zeros with zeros.  To address this, you could try the following variation on the second sample:

```
let ys = [|2uy; 2uy|]
let xs = Array.zeroCreate<byte> 10
Array.iteri (fun i y -> xs.[i] <- y) ys
```

For this approach, you could also use the framework's Array.Copy method:

```
...
System.Array.Copy(ys, xs, ys.Length)
```

This will be much more efficient.  Come to think of it, there's an F# Array.blit, also:

```
...
Array.blit ys 0 xs 0 ys.Length
```

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking this also might work:

```
member this.UP = Array.append [|byte(2);byte(2)|] (Array.zeroCreate 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet one more way

```
[|yield 2uy; yield 2uy; for _ in 2..9 -> 0uy|]
```

But

```
[|2uy; 2uy; 0uy; 0uy; 0uy; 0uy; 0uy; 0uy; 0uy; 0uy|]
```

is pretty easy too.